# How to get the F-Measure for NTLK naive Bayes

Tags: python, nltk

I can get the accuracy:

```
print ("Accuracy result = " + str(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)) )
```

but how do I get the F-measure (or Mean F1-Score)?

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407266/scikits-learn-and-nltk-naive-bayes-classifier-performance-highly-different) mentions some F-measure, but I cannot find the command used for that display.

Comment: the one with f-Measure if the comments is from scikits.

Answer (score 3):

You have to calculate it yourself. You can get the needed values to calculate this from Confusion Matrix.
Look at here: http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html